# What is the proper way to configure Magento + Apache while running multiple stores on multiple domains?

Tags: php, apache, magento

This question has been asked amply all over the internet and on SO -- The available answers are obscured by specific details about everyone's particular installation.  Hopefully this question will help everyone, including me, understand this better.

My question is "How should we configure the Apache .conf file to handle multiple domains?"

(I know the answer "depends".  Hopefully, 80% of the people out there are going to have a basic setup at first and then make it more complex later.)  I hope that's a good assumption.

I'm comparing Magento's install to Wordpress.  Under Wordpress, the "best way" to install it seems to be to put the whole core into a folder called /wordpress.  Then, using Apache rewrite rules and permalinks, obscure the /wordpress folder.  In a multi-domain situation, the Wordpress core smartly handles the whole process for you without much modification of the .htaccess files.  Further, whatever modifications do need to be made, Wordpress can do it for you - or a plugin can.  Gosh, I wish Magento was as easy to install as Wordpress.  But it's not. (yet!)

Under Magento, the term "store" is very misleading when we think about URLs.  So let's ignore it for now and just worry about the lowest level -- the "Store View".  In my case, I have the following:

```
Main Web Site -> Main Web Site Store -> Default Store View    
www.site1.com -> Main Store -> site1_english
www.site2.com -> Main Store -> site2_english
```

- The first column is the domain.
- The second column is the store --
  misleading title for this discussion.
- The last column is the "Store View".

As for where to physically place the files.  Most people, including me, want to leave the Magento core alone.  No changes at all.  So we put that into the htdocs root as follows:

```
/var/www/html/magento
```

This is where everyone gets confused I think.  The Linux distros are not consistent about where this location is.  And worse, lots of people are trying to do this on an economical hosting account.  I'm using EC2 myself.  Ignoring all that...  Stick /magento in your document root.  The next thing you might add is a /wordpress folder.  Yay. Do it later.

In my apache config, I have it setup like this:

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias www.site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento

        <Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

# Other directives here
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "site1"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site2.com
ServerAlias www.site2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento

        <Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

# Other directives here
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "base"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "site2_en"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nowhere
</VirtualHost>
```

The /nowhere folder has an index.html that says "no where".

The situation that I'm seeing is as such:

- Navigate to www.site1.com -> Magento redirects to the Default Store View (on the IP address)
- Navigate to www.site2.com -> Magento redirects to the Default Store View (on the IP address)
- Navigate to the IP address of my server -> Magento displays the Default Store View

The Default Store View's BASE URL is http://my.ip.add.ress

Here are my questions:

1. What are we supposed to put in MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE?  Some sites say "website", some say "store".  What is supposed to go in there?
2. Why don't I ever get to my nowhere site?
3. Why does the www.site1.com keep redirecting to the Default Store View?

Some of the documentation out there talks about creating dedicated folder or copying around index.php or .htaccess.  Or making our own .htaccess.  In this article, I selected the Apache config file.

Why won't that work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the www.site1.com keep redirecting to the Default Store View?

Go to

`System->Configuration->General->Web`

There you should find Base secure and Base unsecure URL for you store. Moreover to the upper left corner you should see the scope of your settings. So for each store view you should change(if possible) URL of your store view.

> What are we supposed to put in MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE? Some sites say "website", some say "store". What is supposed to go in there?

If I don't mistake in code you specify the code of the "object" you want to launch, and in type you specify the type of this object - store or website. **But this is not 100% info.**